# I need to read data from a existing realm data base

Tags: java, android, realm

I have an existing realm database which has passed to Realm object as an asset and configured as default realm.
I also have two model classed that they have to fill with data which retrieved from existing database.
I don't know how to read data, what steps has to take?

first I had to give realm my existing database with following approach:

```
Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .assetFile("assets\\databases.realm")
            .readOnly()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realConfig);
```

then for reading data ;

```
Realm.init(this);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
           RealmResults<Word> words = realm.where(Word.class).equalTo("id",1976).findAll();
        }
    });
    Word testWord = realm.where(Word.class).findFirst();
```

Comment: what have you tried? show your code

Comment: I edited the post and also added the giving existing database approach if it's not appropriate give hint on that too please

Answer (score 0):

You can access the result within a function like this:

```
@Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Word> words = realm.where(Word.class).equalTo("id",1976).findAll();
        displayQueriedResults(words);
        }


displayQueriedResults(RealmResults<Word> words){
    for(Word word : words){
        int i = word.getId(); //do whatever with your result
        String s = word.getName();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks and everything's ok with assigning asset? cause when I use getDefaulConfiguration() method it returns the default realm db which has made internally not my asset